# Setting the log stream name for AWS CloudWatch not getting set from the dotnet sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using the AWS SDK to set up logs on CloudWatch.
Everything is working correctly except the stream name is a GUID. Setting the LogStreamNameSuffix which should set a unique name is not working correctly / is being ignored.

```
AWSTarget awsErrorLogger = new AWSTarget();
awsErrorLogger.LogGroup = "ErrorLogs/" ; 
awsErrorLogger.Layout = LogLayout;
awsErrorLogger.LogStreamNameSuffix = Environment.MachineName;
awsErrorLogger.Region = "us-east-1";

config.AddTarget("AWSLogs", awsErrorLogger);
```

Is there a specific order that it needs to be set or is there a text length limit/requirements

Comment: are you using log4net?

Comment: I'm using NLog.

Comment: Apparently this was fixed about 2 months ago: https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/issues/10